# Where does a reference to an empty data structure point to in memory

Tags: rust

I've noticed some rust functions return references to empty data structures. I'm trying to get a sense for where references of these types point to in memory and why one would want to return a reference to an empty data structure in the first place. For instance where does `&()` point to in memory for the following Rust programs?

```
struct EmptyType;

impl Deref for EmptyType {
    type Target = ();

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        // where does this point to?
        &()
    }
}
```

```
fn main() {
    // where does &a point to
    let a = ();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is guaranteed, but currently [the first is pointing somewhere in the binary address space](https://rust.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,selection:(endColumn:21,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:21,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:21,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:21,startLineNumber:1),source:%27use+std::ops::Deref%3B%0A%0Apub+struct+EmptyType%3B%0A%0Aimpl+Deref+for+EmptyType+%7B%0A++++type+Target+%3D+()%3B%0A%0A++++fn+deref(%26self)+-%3E+%26Self::Target+%7B%0A++++++++//+where+does+this+point+to%3F%0A++++++++%26()%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Rust+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:nightly,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,libs:!(),options:%27-Copt-level%3D3+-Cpanic%3Dabort+-Cdebuginfo%3D0%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:4),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+rustc+nightly+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) and the second somewhere on the stack.

Comment: In what scenario would you want to return a reference to an empty type. The examples I've seen haven't made it completely obvious why they are returning &() as opposed to ()

Comment: @mildog8 Because the trait is expecting you to return a reference?